# Puzzle of $N$ men around a table

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, recreational-mathematics, puzzle

This was asked to me by a friend. $N$ men sit around a circular table. Man 1 has a sword with him and he kills the Man 2, Man 3 picks up this sword and kills the next person i.e. Man 4. Thus the man next to a killed man picks up the sword and kills the one next to him. In the end, which Man will be left behind?

Comment: This is a variation of the [Josephus problem](http://enwp.org/Josephus_problem).

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a special case of the [Josephus problem](http://enwp.org/Josephus_problem).